# Regex - How can I achieve this?

Tags: php, regex

I have regex as `/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/` now I need to add support for unicode characters and so am using `\p{L}` like `'/^[a-zA-Z ]+$\p{L}/'`.

This is not working for me and I am not sure that this is correct way of using it. I am new to regex and would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: »The PHP preg functions, which are based on PCRE, support Unicode when the /u option is appended to the regular expression.« — [Regex Tutorial - Unicode Characters and Properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
/^[\p{L} ]+$/u
```

This will match any string that consists of spaces and any kind of letter from any language. The `u` flag, as Johannes pointed out, makes it match against UTF-8.

Also, I have found [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to be a lot of help for Regular Expressions in general. The link I've provided talks about regular expressions and unicode characters.

Comment: You're missing the `u` option.

Answer (score 1):

You've said your string must begin, then have lots of letters/spaces, then end, THEN have a unicode letter.

I'm unfamiliar with the syntax of your particular regexp library, but I suspect you want

```
/^[\p{L} ]+$/
```

Comment: Unicode can be anywhere and so cant say it to be at one place only

Comment: I meant, the example you'd posted that you'd tried was nonsensical because you were saying you wanted to match unicode letters AFTER the end of the string (represented in the regexp by $).

The regexp I've given you should match any sequence of unicode letters and spaces (one or more).